# Examples of golem_opts when running app using the golem package

Tags: r

I've been trying to develop more advanced apps using this new golem package in R's Shiny and came across this golem_opts that might be interesting, but still haven't seen no one using it. Can someone give examples of options for this function? Thanks in advance.

```
#' Run the Shiny Application
#'
#' @export
#' @importFrom shiny shinyApp
#' @importFrom golem with_golem_options


run_app <- function(...) {
  with_golem_options(
    app = shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server), 
    golem_opts = list(...)
  )
}
```

I expect to get more customizable apps through this new and exiting package called golem.
Also, if possible, could you point some more advanced application running with golem besides the creator's of the package and tutorials?
There is a lack of examples of this package out there.

Comment: Best way is to contact the authors to update their docs. Otherwise, this is off topic because **" SHOW ME THE CODE There is a lack of examples of this package out there."**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check an example [here](https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexample#passing-arguments-to-run_app)

These two examples of passing args are pretty useless here, but they are designed to give you a grasp of what it does.

This example though is intended to show that `golem_opts` can be used in the UI and from the server side.

---

Other examples (from internal apps / client apps) include things like:

- Setting local vs prod in the function to use a prod or dev db

```r
# Run the application
XXX::run_app(local = TRUE)
```

Then :

```r
  if (golem::get_golem_options("local")){
    session$userData$mongo <- mongolite::mongo("XXX")
  } else {
    pass <- readRDS("~/.mongo_con")
    URI <- sprintf(
      "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s", 
      pass$USER, 
      pass$PASS, 
      pass$HOST, 
      pass$DB
    )
    session$userData$mongo <- mongolite::mongo("XXX", "XXX", url = URI)
  }
```

- Setting db usage

```r
# Run the application
XXX::run_app(mongo_db = "dev")
```

Then

```r
session$userData$mongo <- mongolite::mongo(golem::get_golem_options("mongo_db"), "XXX")
```

- Showing / hidding UI elements

```r
# Run the application
XXX::run_app(rights = "admin")
```

Then

```r
fluidPage(
 tagList(
  mod_base_ui("mod_base_1"),
  if (golem::get_golem_options("mongo_db") == "admin"){
   mod_admin_ui("mod_admin_ui"),
  }
 )
)
```

Let me know if that helps,

Colin

---

Ps: asking "SHOW ME THE CODE" and criticising the lack of documentation is pretty rude, btw. Both take a lot of time to write, most of this time coming from package developers' free time, so that you can use it for free.